# Formula to calculate the column number

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have:

[image]

and I want to calculate the numbers highlighted using a formula

[image]

NOTE the ordering of the values in the first image AND the second image vary over time.

Match does not appear to do the trick.

Comment: Well it doesn't work, since you didn't copy my whole forrmula. You forgot to include the last 0, to show that it looks for exact matches. Therefore it should be `=MATCH(A2,Sheet1!$1:$1,0)`.

Comment: `MATCH` will also work if you change the order.

Comment: I cannot change the order. I have no control of the horizontal OR vertucal ordering of CAT, DOG etc.

Answer (score 1):

Since you only want the column number, `MATCH` should suffice:

```
=MATCH(A2,Sheet1!$1:$1,0)
```

Where Sheet1 is the first sheet, where you keep the names in the row

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't `INDEX` and `MATCH` solve this?
im not to sure if I got the question, but if you want to get the values over to the first sheet I would put this in row 2 in the first sheet`INDEX(A:B,MATCH(A$1,'SHEET2'!A:A,0),2)` and drag out as you wish.